# I have a HP Envy 5532 printer that I want to set up with an IP address

Tags: networking, dns, ip, printer

As the title says I want to set up an IP address but the format on the printer is 000.000.000.000 and you cannot delete any of the 0's.

My details are:
IP Address:192.168.1.70
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 192.168.1.1

The printer keeps saying that the IP is not valid. I have tried 192.168.001.070 and it doesn't like it.

Would anyone be able to tell me how to type in these details into the HP format.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this wireless (wifi) or ethernet (wired)? If wireless, have you tried following the setup instructions included with your printer, or at https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05760725 ?

Comment: My mother has an HP Envy series printer; I set it up using the instructions, and had no problem. When I started seeing the printer not consistently get the same IP because of power issues, I went into the router and set up a DHCP reservation for the printer. I didn't try to set the printer up with a manually entered IP address.

Comment: The leading 0's do not matter. Is it possible that some other device already uses 1.70? Try pinging it with the printer disconnected.